# SQL-запрос с LIMIT

Tags: sql

Как сделать sql запрос, чтобы limit доставал строки начиная с N-строки?

Если я делаю, допустим, запрос -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (..) LIMIT n
```

получается, что он достает с 0 по n, а мне нужно с n до n++ (до конца таблицы).

Answer (score 9):

Можно сделать так

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (..) LIMIT n-1, 99999999999 /* число, превышающее число строк в таблице*/
```

Вот вполне точный и более тормознутый вариант:

```
select * table
left join (
select * from table (..) limit 3
) X on (..)
where X.<к.-н.столбец> is NULL
```

Comment: Количество записей можно получить отдельным запросом. Не уверен, что прокатит вложенный.

Comment: Не прокатит.
Однако можно написать вполне точно. Добавил в ответ. Только вот стоит ли оно того? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Мой способ, конечно же, не такой изящный, как первый, но все же рабочий. Не знаю даже, зачем я его привожу, ведь он ноль с палочкой по сравнению с вариантом, предоставленным пользователем [@msi](/users/2339/msi) =)

```
SELECT * FROM qmex_user_friends ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
```

Тут только логика немного другая: не от N до COUNT(ID), а от COUNT(ID) Первые N записей.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id 
                     FROM table  /* какой-то критерия для выборки */ 
                    LIMIT size * N)
 LIMIT size
```

где:

```
size - количество строк для выборки
N - целые числа начиная с нуля, которые определяют "пакет" строк
```

Comment: Интересно, какая версия MySQL допускает использование LIMIT в IN?

Comment: мне сложно ответить на ваш вопрос, т.к. я никогда не работал с mysql. я просто предложил подход которым пользовался когда работал с oracle